# Calculate average motion of points in a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I have a sphere full of individual particles. Each particle has an $(x,y,z)$ co-ordinate and velocity in $(v_x, v_y, v_z)$ directions.

I want to find out if there is any preferred direction of motion for these particles. I suspect in my model that there is an average clockwise motion in the $xy$ plane, but would like to quantify it further.

What techniques exist that might help me work this out. I'm at a loss as to where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

Use the velocities as a vector-valued field $\vec{v}(\vec{x})$.  Use any numerical technique that smooths to find a piecewise differentiable function $\vec{f}(\vec{x})$ estimating that vector field.  Then calculate the curl $\nabla \times \vec{f}$.  If the curl is non-zero by a statistically significant amount, you have shown your effect.

The art here is in choosing a suitable smooting or estimating technique, and then in assessing what value of curl sould be statistically significant -- the latter question depends on the uncertainty estimate in your estimating step.